# What happens to K'un-Lun in the final episode of Iron Fist season 1?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist-2017

In the final episode of the Iron Fist when Danny returns to K'un-Lun, he finds

> a bunch of K'un-lun guards dead and warriors of the hand also dead. He also discovers that K'un-lun itself has disappeared.

I know that maybe this will be explained in a probable season 2. But what could have happened to K'un-Lun? Do the monks have some sort of teleportation power? Maybe there is something in the comic books that explains this?

[image: K'un-Lun]

Comment: There are many times in the show when 'the way' to Kun-lun is described as being 'open' or 'closed'. Danny himself seems to suggest that Kun-lun can't be located on a map. From that, I guessed that this scene simply means that 'the way is closed' again, and that the Hand got in, and Danny can't do anything about it until 'the way' is open again.

Comment: Season 2 of Iron Fist is out on Netflix in the USA at time of writing, by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The K'un Lun that's found in the comics is a bit different from the one portrayed in the show, so it's not clear how much we can take from the source material. But as far as I know, nothing remotely like this has happened in the comics to K'un Lun or any of the other Cities of Heaven.

On Earth-616, where most of Marvel's comics stories take place, the Iron Fist is not the "defender of K'un Lun", and there's no real connection between the Iron Fist and the Hand. So much of the story device of the Iron Fist defending the pass to K'un Lun from The Hand was invented for the show. Instead, the Iron Fist's primary job is to represent K'un Lun in a martial arts contest among the Cities of Heaven to earn the right to appear on Earth every 10 years.

(This was likely the origin of the "tournament" Gao sets up in *Iron Fist*, since the Bride of the Nine Spiders is one of the other city's Immortal Weapons.)

In the most popular Iron Fist stories, Danny spends the bulk of his time as part of a team — first the Heroes for Hire, then the Defenders. We don't really see a whole lot of modern-day K'un Lun in the comics (mostly we see it in flashback). There are a couple of *Iron Fist* stories set there, including one where K'un Lun gets attacked, but nothing that I remember about the city just **disappearing** the way it has in the show.

Answer (score 1):

***SPOILERS FROM DEFENDERS***

Gao is not Crane's Mother, she is one of the Five Fingers of the Hand. They were banished from K'un Lun because the Hand used ground up Dragon bones (Danny implies all dragons are one, Shao Lao the Undying). There is a line in Episode 8 of Defenders that implies the Hand killed everyone in K'un Lun...

Comment: Can you provide the line as evidence?

Answer (score 0):

In the comic books, the order that the immortal weapons finish in the tournament held by the kingdoms of Heaven determines when each city’s path to Earth’s dimension is open.

So, my theory is that, if the tournament that Madame Gao held is indeed the tournament of the Seven Kingdoms of Heaven, then when Danny won the tournament it meant that the pass to Kun Lun isn't just open at the time Danny thinks it is any more.

As far as the Hand’s Warriors being defeated outside the gates goes, I'm not really sure whether they got in or if they sent more protectors to the pass and successfully defended the kingdom from an attack and then the pass closed after the attack was thwarted.

I also believe that Madame Gao is the crane mother because of how she set up the tournament and how you see her sitting behind Danny's best friend at the end of the season. In the comics the crane mother sent Danny's best friend to kill him for abandoning the kingdom of heaven and to claim back the power of the Iron Fist, but before he decides to do this he tries to get Danny to come back.